# Ant design Tree in React not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, antd

I'm using a state management to handle websocket updates. If I render the values everything is fine, but when I'm using the Antd Tree component, it always shows the previous state.

```
const serviceTreeData = useServiceTreeStore((store) => store.serviceTreeData);
const [treeData, setTreeData] = React.useState(serviceTreeData);
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = serviceTreeData.map(data => cloneDeep(data))
    setTreeData(data);
}, [serviceTreeData]);
```

I tried to deep copy in case if that's the problem, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ever get this sorted out?

Comment: unfortunately not, I made a workaround and using antd tree only static...